# How to loop through a folder of subfolders and read the images inside each subfolder?

Tags: python, mediapipe

Currently, I have a python program that is able to run without error. However, it is only able to run through a subfolder of images and extract the x, y, z coordinates of the 468 facial landmarks in each image. I want to edit it as such that the program will loop through the many subfolders and read the many images inside each subfolder. What needs to be stated in the "path" function and what needs to be edited in my code stated below? The folder is named as "nopain" and the subfolders are named as "1, 2, 3, etc..."

```
import os
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time
from os import listdir
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
import glob
import numpy
path = glob.glob("C:/Users/Downloads/Mac master DB_no overlap/nopain/1/*.png")
fh = open('out.txt', 'w')
for file in path:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
    mpFaceMesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh
    facemesh = mpFaceMesh.FaceMesh(max_num_faces=1)
    drawSpec = mpDraw.DrawingSpec(thickness=1, circle_radius=2)
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    result = facemesh.process(rgb_image)
    if result.multi_face_landmarks:
        for faceLms in result.multi_face_landmarks:
            mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, faceLms, mpFaceMesh.FACEMESH_CONTOURS,
            drawSpec, drawSpec)
            for lm in faceLms.landmark:
                print(lm, file, file = fh)
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
fh.close()
```

Comment: This is going to be incredibly CPU intensive. Have you considered multiprocessing? If not, you should. Also, why are you calling *cv2.imshow()* on the last image processed? Seems a bit odd

Comment: @OldBill sorry I have not tried multiprocessing, how can that be done? also what should 
I change the "cv2.imshow()" to then?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post by deleting its content.

Answer (score 1):

You need a recursive glob as follows. Note the double asterisk

```
path = glob.glob("C:/Users/Downloads/Mac master DB_no overlap/nopain/**/*.png", recursive=True)
```

Comment: works for small folder with 25 subfolders but does not run fully for large folders with 2000+ subfolders

Comment: @Mohamed In what way does it not work? Have you also considered os.walk()?

Comment: the program is only able to print until the 26th subfolder. However, there is a total of almost 2000+ subfolders in the folder

Comment: @Mohamed Are you suggesting that the glob just stops returning values, raises an exception, what?

Comment: no exception raised, but yes the glob stops returning values after 26th subfolder for some reason

Comment: @Mohamed I suggest you raise this as a bug https://docs.python.org/3/bugs.html

Comment: Might there be symlinks or hidden directories not followed by `glob`?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the pathlib module https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

This should work:

```py
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path("C:/Users/Downloads/Mac master DB_no overlap/nopain").rglob("*.png")
```

For example
I am using bash to generate some dummy directories and files to show how it works..

```bash
$ mkdir -p {1,2,3,4}/dir{1,2,3}
$ touch {1,2,3,4}/dir{1,2,3}/img.png
$ touch {1,2,3,4}/img1.png
$ tree
.
├── 1
│   ├── dir1
│   │   └── img.png
│   ├── dir2
│   │   └── img.png
│   ├── dir3
│   │   └── img.png
│   └── img1.png
├── 2
│   ├── dir1
│   │   └── img.png
│   ├── dir2
│   │   └── img.png
│   ├── dir3
│   │   └── img.png
│   └── img1.png
├── 3
│   ├── dir1
│   │   └── img.png
│   ├── dir2
│   │   └── img.png
│   ├── dir3
│   │   └── img.png
│   └── img1.png
└── 4
    ├── dir1
    │   └── img.png
    ├── dir2
    │   └── img.png
    ├── dir3
    │   └── img.png
    └── img1.png
```

Here is the output using the pathlib module:

```py
>>> import pathlib
>>> for p in pathlib.Path("./").rglob("*.png"):
...     print(p)
...
2/img1.png
2/dir3/img.png
2/dir1/img.png
2/dir2/img.png
1/img1.png
1/dir3/img.png
1/dir1/img.png
1/dir2/img.png
3/img1.png
3/dir3/img.png
3/dir1/img.png
3/dir2/img.png
4/img1.png
4/dir3/img.png
4/dir1/img.png
4/dir2/img.png
```

Comment: do I have to manually name the 2000+ subfolders one by one?

Comment: No - I only generated an example of what your folder structure might look like to demonstrate. (I updated my answer to include the block you should try)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a recursive glob as others have suggested, I would recommend using the following code so that you have access to the name of the subfolder currently being processed - which will likely be useful for you to name the output files with the landmarks.

```py
base_path = Path("C:/Users/Downloads/Mac master DB_no overlap/nopain")
subfolders = [item for item in base_path.iterdir() if item.is_dir()]
for subfolder in subfolders:
    with open(f'out_{str(subfolder.name)}.txt', 'w') as fh:
        print(f"Working on subfolder '{str(subfolder)}'...")
        for file in subfolder.glob("*.png"):
            img = cv2.imread(str(file))
            mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
            mpFaceMesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh
            facemesh = mpFaceMesh.FaceMesh(max_num_faces=1)
            drawSpec = mpDraw.DrawingSpec(thickness=1, circle_radius=2)
            rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            result = facemesh.process(rgb_image)
            if result.multi_face_landmarks:
                for faceLms in result.multi_face_landmarks:
                    mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, faceLms, mpFaceMesh.FACEMESH_CONTOURS,
                    drawSpec, drawSpec)
                    for lm in faceLms.landmark:
                        print(lm, file, file=fh)
        cv2.imshow("image", img)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

With this code, the output files with landmarks will be named appropriately: e.g., `out_1.txt` for subfolder `1`, `out_2.txt` for subfolder `2`, etc.

You can also save `out.txt` to the subfolder itself. Since `subfolder` is a `pathlib.Path` object, use the line `with open(str(subfolder / 'out.txt'), 'w') as fh:`.

Comment: fh = open(f'out_{str(subfolder)}.txt', 'w')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'out_C:\\Users\\\\Downloads\\Mac master DB_no overlap\\nopain\\1.txt'

Comment: Received that error @Raj K

Comment: My apologies, it should be `fh = open(f'out_{str(subfolder.name)}.txt', 'w')`. `str(subfolder)` returns the full path, but we just want the name (e.g., `1`) in this case. I'll update my answer to fix this.

Comment: not sure why i got the following error: "img = cv2.imread(file)
TypeError: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'"

Comment: My bad! It's because `file` is a `pathlib.Path` object, so it needs to be cast to a `str` - another oversight of mine. I'll update my answer, which should instead use the line `img = cv2.imread(str(file))`.

Comment: Also, this may be a bit unrelated, but I believe mediapipe has a dedicated "video mode" that uses landmarks from past frames to better predict landmarks in future frames. If you're interested, I'd be happy to help you modify your code to use it. See https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/face_mesh#python-solution-api for more details.

Comment: not sure why some of the subfolders do not return any texts, also what can be modified to print all the data in just one text file?

Comment: I'll leave that debugging to you, as I think this discussion is straying a bit from the original question. If you have other questions, please feel free to make new posts on SO!